# Extracting data from an InfoPath XML file in a Sharepoint document library

Tags: xml, sharepoint, infopath

I have a document library that contains InfoPath files, along with some other metadata.  I have a request from a user that is trying to create a list on another subsite and wants to create a view out of the metadata in this list, as well as some other items that the users enters when they submit the InfoPath form but which is not available when choosing columns to show in the view.

How would I go about querying this information, specifically for use in a column as part of a view on another list?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what version of SharePoint and what version of InfoPath you are using.
You could get better help if were more specific. Following applies to both 2007 and 2010 versions.

That

```
...some other items that the users enters when they submit the InfoPath form 
but which is not available when choosing columns to show in the view.
```

is so because you chose it to be that way.

The simplest way would be to make fields on your InfoPath form available as columns in SharePoint. To do that use 'Property promotion' feature in InfoPath Designer.

Now the other question is how the new column(s) be made available in another site.
There are several ways programmed workflows being one such. `List Event recievers` is another by using [`ItemAdded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded.aspx) Method.

I am assuming there are no attachments, otherwise things might take slightly different turn in terms of options available. You can use **binary streams** to read file overriding the same `ItemAdded()` method and programmatically set properties of attachments in destination list.

This MSDN blog might be helpful.
[Copy listitems from one custom list to another.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsnoiwb/archive/2009/04/30/copy-listitems-from-one-custom-list-to-another-then-move-them-into-subfolders.aspx)